# Is the loaded assembly DEBUG or RELEASE?

Tags: c#, debugging, configuration, release

How can I find out if a loaded assembly is a DEBUG or RELEASE version?

Yes, I could use a method like this:

```
public static bool IsDebugVersion() {
#if DEBUG
    return true;
#else
    return false;
#endif
}
```

But this is only usable in my own code.
I need a check at runtime (for third-party assemblies), like this:

```
public static bool IsDebugVersion(Assembly assembly) {
    ???
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(bool)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk0t7cax%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a list of attributes, then look for `DebuggableAttribute`, and then if that was found, see if the property `IsJITTrackingEnabled` is set to `true`:

```
public static bool IsAssemblyDebugBuild(Assembly assembly)
{
    foreach (var attribute in assembly.GetCustomAttributes(false))
    {
        var debuggableAttribute = attribute as DebuggableAttribute;
        if(debuggableAttribute != null)
        {
            return debuggableAttribute.IsJITTrackingEnabled;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The above taken from [here](http://ardalis.com/determine-whether-an-assembly-was-compiled-in-debug-mode).

Alternative using LINQ:

```
public static bool IsAssemblyDebugBuild(Assembly assembly)
{
    return assembly.GetCustomAttributes(false)
        .OfType<DebuggableAttribute>()
        .Any(i => i.IsJITTrackingEnabled);
}
```

Comment: How can this be correct?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggableattribute.isjittrackingenabled says `Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, JIT tracking information is always enabled during debugging, and this property value is ignored.`

Comment: @JohnZabroski the property is ignored for the purposes of internal debugger processes, but it is still valid for determining if an assembly was compiled in debug mode.